# Where to put jsp files within a GWT project?

Tags: java, jsp, gwt

Within a GWT project (using ant), if I wanted to my host page to be a jsp file, would I just put this jsp file, in the war directory, or anywhere else? And would I need to put anything in my web.xml in order to run the jsp? I'll be running on tomcat 7 in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See
http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/6.1/tutorials/fnb/dev_intro/j2ee_overview8.html
for details on the directory structure of a war

and http://www.xyzws.com/JSPfaq/how-to-config-a-jsp-file-in-webxml/2
for a guide on how to configure the jsp in the web.xml

Here is a basic guide on both configuring the structure of the war and configuring the web.xml: http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/tomcat/index.html

Basically if you want your jsp to be public you just need to place the jsp somewhere outside of the WEB-INF directory.

Answer (score 1):

GWT modules are stored on a web server as a set of JavaScript and related files. In order to run the module, it must be loaded from a web page of some sort. Any html page can include a GWT application by using the `script` tag.

A host html page does not have to be static content. It could also be generated by a servlet, or by a jsp page.

See the documentation: [HTML Host Pages](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage)

Where to place the jsp: [Standard Directory and Package Layout](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage)

[image]

Comment: Where do I need to put the jsp file? In the war directory or somewhere else?

Comment: I know how to load the GWT module, I simply want to know where I should put the jsp, e.g so if someone goes to mysite.com/foo.jsp, it loads up the foo.jsp file.

Comment: In our project we put them into ...main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp